# como podria realizar este ejercicio?

Tags: python, array, algoritmos

he intentado realizar este ejercicio pero la verdad es que no le he hallado la forma de resolverlo,creo qeu voy bien hasta donde empieza el segundo ciclo for pero de ahi no se que sigue el ejercicio es este "Construya un programa que lea el tamaño de un arreglo de enteros y los valores del arreglo y que diga si
existe un número que se repita mínimo tres veces. En caso de que exista el número, debe indicar qué número es"
y este es mi codigo 
contador=0

```
import numpy as np
numero=np.any
for i in numero:
  for j in numero:
    if numero == j:
     contador+=1
print(contador,numero)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Esto parece python. que tiene que ver power center aca?

Comment: disculpa a que te refieres con power center?y si, es python

Comment: Agregaste como etiquetas de tu pregunta array, algoritmos, y power center. en que lenguaje estas programando? ajusta las etiquetas como corresponda...

Comment: estoy en python y ya corregí las etiquetas gracias

Comment: nunca agregaste la etiqueta python :/.. en que momento el contador vuelve a cero si el numero que estas mirando no sirve? en que momento controlas que llegaste o pasaste de 3 con determinado numero? esas son las cosas que le faltan a tu algoritmo...

Comment: esas son las que no se como implementar en el código

Comment: Si que sabes ;). Una es un if... que ya tenes uno ahi.. y la otra es poner contador en 0... que tambien sabes porque le sumas cosas a contador...

Comment: que se supone que coloque en el if?

Comment: En genral no hay expertos en python a estas horas, y yo no se python... pero el enunciado de tu ejercico dice que tiene qie tener ese if.. (en que momento queres parar de dar vueltas y decir este numero se repite 3 veces?)

Comment: se supone que para cuando termine de recorrer el arreglo

Comment: Todo el arreglo? O una vuelta del arreglo? Porque estas comparando el mismo consigo mismo. Probaste hacer este ejercicio en papel antes de programarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu problema es más bien de enfoque que de Python. La sintaxis python parece que la controlas  correctamente y ciertamente el problema no requiere más características que puedas desconocer. Todo se hace con asignaciones, bucles y condicionales. Y con una estructura de datos llamada "diccionario" que sirve para asociar claves con valores (la clave en nuestro caso será cada número que vayamos observando y el valor será el número de veces que ha aparecido)

Por tanto voy a ayudarte un poco con el pseudocódigo y te dejo que intentes por ti mismo convertirlo en sintaxis python. Es la mejor forma de ir aprendiendo, que supongo que es de lo que se trata.

Pseudocódigo:

```
Inicializar array, que llamaremos numeros
Inicializar diccionario llamado "repeticiones" con el valor {} (diccionario vacio)
Para cada numero del array numeros hacer:
   si el numero estaba entre las claves del diccionario "repeticiones":
       incrementar el valor asociado a esa clave
   si no:
       asignar 1 como valor asociado a esa clave

# Al salir del bucle anterior ya tienes en el diccionario cada número
# hallado y el número de veces que aparece

Para cada pareja (clave, valor) en el diccionario "repeticiones":
   Si valor es mayor o igual a 3:
      # Lo hemos encontrado
      Imprimir valor
      Salir del bucle (break)
else:  # El bucle se ha agotado
    Imprimir "No hay ninguno"
```

Algunos detalles sobre los diccionarios en python:

- Puedes mirar si una clave está entre las claves de un diccionario con la expresión `if clave in diccionario`
- Si está, puedes acceder a su valor para asignarlo o cambiarlo con `diccionario[clave]`
- El método `diccionario.items()` te da la lista de parejas `(clave,valor)` que necesitas para el bucle final

Sobre la inicialización del array

- Has usado `numpy` ¿es esto un requisito? Porque no lo necesitas, ya que los números podrían simplemente estar guardados en una lista, con algo como:

  ```
  numeros = [1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 10, 8, 2, 3]
  ```
- Si tienes que usar `numpy`, lo que has hecho de `numeros = np.any` está mal. El método `any()` es para ver si algún elemento de una serie de booleanos es True, no tiene nada que ver con inicializar arrays. No es para generar números al azar como pareces pensar. Para esto sería por ejemplo:

  ```
  numeros = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=15)
  ```

  Que te generaría 15 enteros aleatorios entre 1 y 10

Comment: hola muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero me quedo una duda ¿como se utiliza el diccionario?

Comment: Ya te di las pistas básicas. `repeticiones = {}` lo crea vacío. `if numero in repeticiones` te da `True` si `numero` es alguna de las claves de ese diccionario. `repeticiones[numero]=1` crea esa clave y le da el valor inicial 1. `repeticiones[numero] += 1` incrementa el valor asociado con esa clave. `repeticiones.items()` te da una lista con las parejas (numero, valor) que te servirá para iterar en el bucle final.

Comment: tambien debo de importar numpy?

Comment: Sólo si vas a usarlo. Depende un poco de qué espere quien te haya pedido este ejercicio. El enunciado menciona array, lo que hace pensar en numpy, pero puede implementarse la misma idea usando listas. Depende de si has estudiado o no sobre numpy. Para lo de los diccionarios no es necesario, pues éstos son parte del lenguaje Python y no dependen de ningún modulo externo.

Comment: si no utilizo numpy me toca definir el interior del arreglo ?

Comment: Y si lo usas también. Lo de rellenarlo con números aleatorios es solo para probar, pero tu enunciado dice que los números los debe introducir el usuario. Si usas una lista, puedes comenzar por una lista vacía `numeros=[]` y hacer un bucle en el que vayas añadiendo más números `numeros.append(int(n))`, siendo `n` el número que has leído del usuario mediante `input()`. Entiendo que cómo hacer estas cosas te las tienen que haber explicado antes de pedirte este programa, no?

Comment: es que solo explicaron una parte de psudocodigo y nos dijo que hiciéramos como nos imagináramos en python, el problema donde dice que el usuario debe de digitar los numeros?

Comment: Al inicio, donde dice _"Construya un programa que lea el tamaño de un arreglo de enteros y los valores del arreglo"_. Es decir, el programa debe **leer** primero el tamaño del arreglo (cuántos elementos tendrá) y después los valores. Se entiende que el primer número es para después hacer un bucle que se repita ese número de veces, para ir leyendo el resto de valores. No dice explícitamente que se los pida al usuario, pero ¿de dónde va a leerlos si no? La otra opción sería de un fichero, que sería más difícil. Lo que en todo caso no dice es que los datos "te los inventes" en el código.

Comment: quedaria  algo parecido a esto?
numero=([2,2,4,2,5,2,2,1,4,6,3])
repeticiones={}
for i in range(0,9):
    if numero==repeticiones:
        repeticiones+=1
    else:
        repeticiones=1
    for j in range(repeticiones):
        if repeticiones >=3:
            print(repeticiones)

Comment: Pues la verdad que no... no se parece en nada a eso :-( En lo que has escrito hay tantas cosas mal que no sabría por donde empezar, y lo que es peor, temo que no me entenderías aunque te lo contara, pues ese código muestra un gran desconocimiento de qué es una variable, una lista, un índice, incluso la comparación de igualdad. Por dar alguno de los errores ¿cómo comparas `numero` que es una lista con `repeticiones` que es un diccionario? No se puede. ¿Cómo comparas `repeticiones` con 3? El primero es un diccionario, el segundo es un entero. Creo que deberías empezar por algo mucho más simple.

Comment: es el ejercicio que nos dejaron no puedo pasar a otro

Comment: Bueno, pues puedo ayudarte, pero no quiero darte la solución, quiero que la vayas descubriendo. De modo que ¿por qué no intentas ejecutar el código que has puesto en tu anterior comentario, y después abres otra pregunta nueva, para preguntar por los errores que encuentres? De este modo puedo poner en una respuesta más extensa (que en estos comentarios no me cabe) lo que tienes mal, para que sigas intentándolo